# Reading badly formatted data in Firebase: can't convert object of type

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created classes for each of my data types and use them to read snapshot values whenever possible:

`MyClass my = snapshot.getValue(MyClass.class);`

Everything is fine until I try to read a particular record:

`com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type java.lang.Boolean`

Oops. It turns out that another client mistakenly wrote the string literal `"true"` instead of the boolean value `true` to a child of this record. Many of my properties including this one are optional. Is it possible through annotations or otherwise for Firebase to still read this object and just ignore properties that are not of the expected type/format, or do I have to deal with this exception and drop the entire record?

Comment: Instead of ignoring the faulty data on reading, I'd fix it in the database and [use validation rules to prevent further data corruption](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sure, but if something does slip in I'd rather be able to (selectively) get a partial record than have to wrap every read in a try-catch

Comment: Can you please share your code and json tree??